# Callback on mobile web in ios using square point of sale API. It get error saying Uncaught Typeerror - cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, square-connect

I am setting up an online payment interface using POS API of square. I have been trying to extract information from the page URL and print it on screen.

I tried passing a test string with the URL in it and it showed no error. So now i am wondering if this is because there are some hidden characters in the page URL.

```
function getTransactionInfo(URL) { 
  //page URL is being passed as an argument to the function
  console.log("URL: " + URL);

  var data = decodeURI(URL.searchParams.get('data'));
  console.log("data:  " + data);

  var transactionInfo = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log("transactionInfo: " + transactionInfo);
  return transactionInfo;
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at getTransactionInfo (callback.js:24)

I expect the information in URL to be displayed.

The URL is:

https://ha6017.github.io/callback.html?data=%7B"status":"ok","transaction_id":"7lGD3VkUzJn3U5NxNzJ288seV","client_transaction_id":"455A27FA-FFFC-46C1-A79A-FA7359DD4119"%7D

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue. Can you provide the input to your function, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: The input to my function is this URL:  https://ha6017.github.io/callback.html?data=%7B"status":"ok","transaction_id":"7lGD3VkUzJn3U5NxNzJ288seV","client_transaction_id":"455A27FA-FFFC-46C1-A79A-FA7359DD4119"%7D

In this is want to parse the data as JSON using the function i posted above. The line :
var data = decodeURI(URL.searchParams.get('data'));

this line of code keeps giving me an error saying- Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

What do you think is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing a string to your function when your function is expecting a [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). The string type does not have a `searchParams` property. The URL type does.

```js
const myUrl = new URL('https://ha6017.github.io/callback.html?data=%7B%22status%22:%22ok%22,%22transaction_id%22:%227lGD3VkUzJn3U5NxNzJ288seV%22,%22client_transaction_id%22:%22455A27FA-FFFC-46C1-A79A-FA7359DD4119%22%7D');

const info = getTransactionInfo(myUrl);

console.log('Transaction info: ', info);

function getTransactionInfo(url) {
  var data = decodeURI(url.searchParams.get('data'));
  var transactionInfo = JSON.parse(data);

  return transactionInfo;
}
```

Be careful, IE doesn't support the `URL` object.

Comment: Thanks alot. That solved the error. I was not using URL object to pass the URL but only the string.